# jQuery code should change something simple in web page by using JSON data from two external device buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my school project. I have tried to do it as simple as possible, just to change background color in web page etc..

I work with an external device with two buttons (microbit a and b) -connected in serial port, writing data string "aa" or "bb". Then python code reads it inside for ever loop and writes it in json file, where this code should be able to enter in. With these changing json time stamps, this code should read which button was pressed latest and then do what is written in conditions.

json files reference time is changing all the time, by the button press.

I am very thankful for any help, we have been doing this project already quite long, this is final stage but as you see ,but i am not yet there.

As this does not execute anything after get json line... it did once, and till final >>if, but then it stopped..why? I dont know.. I am not good enough in this.

Final part of the code curly braces etc, i cant anymore count which one is too much or >>what is missing?! ...

my json example: `{"REF": 1624391142, "aa": 1624391140, "bb": 1624391142}`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("jQuery starts");

  var d = new Date();
  var time = d.getTime();
  setInterval(function () {
    // loop that reads every 2 sec json file,

    $.getJSON("data.json"),
      function (json) {
        console.log("test", time);

        //what is REF-time <= time
        if (time <= json.REF) {
          // any changes?

          time = json.REF;
          console.log(" REF", time);
          pressedBtn = "";
          jQuery.each(json, function (key, value) {
            //searhing

            if (value == time && key != "REF") {
              pressed = key;
              console.log("Working");
            }

            if (pressedBtn == "aa") {
              $("body").show("active"); //background color change
              console.log("pressed", pressedBtn);
              $("#toshow").show("toshow"); // comment div
            }

            if (pressedBtn == "bb") {
              $("#toshow").hide("toshow"); //comment div
              console.log("pressed", pressedBtn);
            }
          });
        }
      };
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I see at least one syntax error in there. Have you checked the dev console in the browser? See the documentation for how to [use getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), you have the parens in the wrong spot. I can't be sure that's the entirety of your problem, but fix that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I reformatted your code so it's easier to read. This will probably also solve your problem with counting the braces. An easy way to format your code is using [prettier's playground](https://prettier.io/playground/).

Comment: Thank you for your effort, i did try these suggestions, but the code does pick my json file and is updating it all the time in my console. So that part works, from some reason it does not enter to the loops. Is there a syntax error?

Comment: $.getJSON("data.json"),function (json) {  <-- it must somehow work till this point, as i can see json.data in network tab in console. But whatever i try to console log is not appearing after that, so i guess the code stops right there..

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood you and maybe this is your solution check this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(doSomething,2000);
});

function doSomething(){
  console.log("do something");
  setTimeout(doSomething,2000);
}
```

this function is execute every 2 seconds like you want in your code

i hope i have help you

Answer (score 0):

[Ok, here is a pick what was wrong. I somehow had added parenthes there right side of the json, where is shouldnt be, thats how the whole block got stuck, i am appologising for taking anyones time. All these marks and syntaxes make one crazy..
Thank you anyway, this community is amazing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMzFp.jpg)